# WARNING JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component j_idt51

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation

I'm getting this warning in my application

> JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component j_idt51

What is the reason for this warning and how can I resolve it? The strange thing is that the component id `j_idt51` is not in the rendered page. If I look to the HTML of the generated page there is no element with id `j_idt51`.

Comment: The warning is even more annoying since our production Glassfish log does not show the `xhtml` site, markup where the error occurs and i cannot find it in development.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This warning will occur whenever you use an (implicit) navigation outcome in the `outcome` attribute of `<h:link>` or `<h:button>`, which does **not** represent a valid view ID.

E.g.

```
<h:link ... outcome="viewIdWhichDoesNotExist" />
<h:button ... outcome="viewIdWhichDoesNotExist" />
```

Additionally, the `<h:link>` will render a `<span>` element instead of an `<a>` element.

The solution is obvious: use a valid view ID, or make at least sure that the desired view is resolveable by [`ConfigurableNavigationHandler#getNavigationCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ConfigurableNavigationHandler.html#getNavigationCase%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Note that some starters use for an unknown reason even a full URL like `http://google.com` as outcome value of `<h:link>`:

```
<h:link value="Go to Google" outcome="http://google.com" />
```

This abuse would then also yield exactly this warning. You should be using `<h:outputLink>` or just `<a>` instead.

As to the absence of a HTML element with the same ID as the JSF component, this may happen when you didn't explicitly specify the JSF component's `id` attribute. The JSF component ID does then not necessarily end up in the generated HTML output. Assigning those components a fixed ID should help better in nailing down the cause.

Comment: Excelent es allways ... I had a h:link in my code that was obsolete.

Comment: Yup, my `<h:link>` "outcome" attribute was pointed at a file that didn't exist in the filesystem.  As soon as I put the file there, my link worked and the error went away  Thanks @BalusC

Comment: JSF should provide a single link component with support for all properties like `href, outcome, action, value` and rendering depending on what is provided. This would be more user / developer orientated then the current technical approach.